# Django default queryset and widget for ModelForm custom field

Tags: python, django

I have a `Site` model, and I am trying to create a `SiteSelectorField` that extends `django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, that uses my custom `SiteSelectorWidget` and `Site.objects.all()` as the queryset

Without the custom form field, my forms.py code looks like this (and works):

```
sites = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Site.objects.all(), widget=SiteSelectorWidget())
```

I would like to limit the arguments passed, so I can do this

```
sites = SiteSelectorField()
```

But when I create the SiteSelectorField class, as below, Django tells me "SiteSelectorField' object has no attribute 'validators"

```
class SiteSelectorField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

  queryset = Site.objects.all()
  widget = SiteSelectorWidget()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

How can I specify a default queryset and widget for this field so they don't need to be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `def __init__` method and code. By putting "pass" inside there, you're overriding the default functionality of `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which your class inherits from, that would utilize the queryset.

Edit:

Re-structure your `__init__` method like so:

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if not 'queryset' in kwargs:
          kwargs['queryset'] = Site.objects.all()
      return super(SiteSelectorField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I considered this, but when I remove that method the django server doesn't load:

File "/vagrant/projects/bluehorse/bluehorse/apps/asset_mgmt/forms.py", line 19, in PhotoUploadForm
    sites = SiteSelectorField()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Comment: Please see my edit, it allows you to pass in a `queryset` kwarg and defines it if it is not there.